# How to abort Jenkins job if a triggered build failes

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins which triggers another one.
How do I make the job abort if the triggered one fails?
Thanks
Gil

Answer (score 3):

You can open http://$HOST/jenkins/job/$PROJECT/$BUILD/stop

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't think there is something built-in. You'll have to check on the triggered build in your build script I guess and if it failed you fail as well. Before you trigger it you can get the next build number from http://$HOSTs/jenkins/job/$PROJECT/api/json and then check the build status on http://$HOST/jenkins/job/$PROJECT/$BUILD/api/json

Answer (score 3):

Use parametrized trigger plugin [from here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Use it as a build step ("Trigger/call builds on other projects"), check "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" box, and choose "Fail this build step if the triggered build is worse or equal to FAILURE".

Comment: This approach makes sense, and the build is marked as failed, but it does not fail-fast. In my case, I have a jenkins jobs that kicks off two `Trigger/call builds on other projects` jobs in sequence (subproject 1 and 2). However, if subproject 1 fails, subproject 2 should not start, but it does

Answer (score 1):

You can add the *post build task* to the triggered job that will:

- run if `Finished: FAILURE` found in the build log,
- execute shell:
  `curl "$UPSTREAM_BUILD/stop" >/dev/null`

`$UPSTREAM_BUILD` neds to be specified by parameter or you can determine it somehow using API...

I am currently setting up my matrix builds to abort all other configurations if one failed and it works as above.